# How to post on pages using Facebook Graph API in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've newly started working with Facebook graph API, what I want to do is that I want to create an application not to redirect on any domain
just a application which runs like we play farm villa in side of facebook and the user will give permission to post on there pages

then my app will be able to Post what ever they want on their pages and there will a cron that will delete post after couple of minutes.

I've one example of this application but it on website i want to do it in app
the example can be seen here

http://fb.groupdivvy.com/index.php

Comment: What would be the point of posting stuff in the first place, and then deleting it again a few minutes later? And are you actually talking about posting onto a page’s wall/timeline, or just to a user’s wall/timeline?

Comment: yeah basically it's for kind of s4s activity, that's why they have to delete Post auto. and secondly want to post or update status of page's timeline not profile